# jquery search box + Ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

i made search box. I used  http://www.ajaxblender.com/auto-completer-using-jquery.html

But I want to create 3 different (searching in posts, other in posts, 3rd in both)

But when i tried, script always going to rpc.php

I'm using:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
// Safely inject CSS3 and give the search results a shadow
var cssObj = { 'box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // Added when CSS3 is standard
'-webkit-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // Safari
'-moz-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px'}; // Firefox 3.5+
$("#suggestions").css(cssObj);

// Fade out the suggestions box when not active
$("input").blur(function(){
$('#suggestions').fadeOut();
});
});

function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
$('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
} else {
$.post("rpc_page.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
$('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
$('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
});
}
}
```

But when i push my search, i saw results from rpc.php?

What can be the reason?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem but  you should use GET ($.get) instead of POST for searching.

Comment: Have you examined rpc_page.php to see if their is a redirect/handler, possibly based on the request type? I.e., as @praxmatig mentioned, it is expecting GET, and seeing POST and redirecting you?

Comment: I can't found some reason. Just didn't work. It's post $.ajax query... and url is rpc_page.php